# How to test styles changes on hover with cypress

Tags: html, css, cypress, e2e-testing

I want to test styles when hover on rows of table but I can't achieve that:

This is my test code:

```
  it("Table rows hover styles should be correct", () => {
    cy.get("table>tbody>tr").each(($el, index, $list) => {
      $el.trigger("mouseover");
      expect($el).to.have.css("background-color", "rgb(242, 242, 242)");
    });
  });
```

but the `background-color` value is what is before hover.

This is cypress error:

`expected '<tr>' to have CSS property 'background-color' with the value 'rgb(242, 242, 242)', but the value was 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with cypress validations, it is possible the test to got executed before hover is finished, and with cypress it will wait for it:

```
it("Table rows hover styles should be correct", () => {
    cy.get("table>tbody>tr").each(($el, index, $list) => {
      $el.trigger("mouseover");
      $el.should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(242, 242, 242)');
    });
  });
```